# manage UICollectionView frame dynamically

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am managing the frame of `UICollectionView`.
What I have to do is, increase the frame of UICollectionViewCell according to the content of the cell.
I am succeed in it some portion.

but I am facing the problem in managing the cells near and below to other.

Here is the thing what I am getting,
but I want it to be managed in proper manner.

What I am doing wrong.
Here is my code.

```
NSString *sth=[SampleText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *result=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d", sth.length];
NSLog(@"resuult lenght :- %@",result);

int framecount = [result integerValue];

return CGSizeMake(300, framecount+150);
```

Where sample text is my array in which text that is over the cell is stored.

any specific layout to achieve this task....?

[image]